# Is there a way to prevent MFMailComposeViewController from sending an email?

Tags: iphone, email

I use an MFMailComposeViewController in an app to make it easy for the user to send me support requests. However, I get a lot of emails with the default message (+ the user's signature), but without any additional info added. I'm guessing this is because a kid is using the device and they're just mashing buttons. Is there any way to detect this case and have it not send the email?

Comment: Do you need any further information? I'd be glad to help.

Comment: If you can do the impossible, sure :) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

From the apple docs:

> Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the
>   interface.